# Two versions of python on linux. How to install packages to specific version of python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, pip

I am using Linux CentOs server. In my server two version of python were installed - 2.6 and 2.7. Both path are entered in to path variable.

I am trying to install pip using following command:

```
> sudo yum install python-pip
```

But it installed to python2.6 (`/usr/bin/python`). So If I am trying to install package to python using pip it goes to python2.6. For example

```
> pip install XlsxWriter
```

First of all I want to install pip to python2.7 version and then have to some packages. Path of python2.7 is `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. How do I manage packages for different versions of python? (I don't want to change my default python version (2.6).)

My second question is... My project needs 8 python packages. How do I install all packages in a single command? Is there any concept like package.json (which is used for nodejs) or composer.json (which is used for php) in python? I heard about setup.py but I could not clear about that. Is this setup.py concept similar to package.json?

Comment: For the first question: I'd download and install pip manually, running the version of python you want when you execute the installer. For the second question: `pip freeze > requirements.txt;  pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have control over what Python version you're using, I'd suggest considering [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

You can then create a stand-alone virtual environment for each project and use the Python version you need.

This will create a virtual environment for your project with Python 2.7, install `<package>` and deactivate the virtual environment.

```
cd my_project_folder
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install <package>
deactivate
```

As for your second question, I recommend using `pip freeze` and `pip install -r`...

First, install all the packages you need:

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install <package1>, <package2>,...
```

Then save the list of packages with their current versions:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create a `requirements.txt` file that you can distribute with the project. When somebody wants to install all the dependencies, they will need to do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

For Python 3, virtual environments are supported by default - [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: to install pip in the version you want: python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m ensurepip and then you can use with python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m pip install PACKAGEYOUWANT

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two python versions installed 2.7 and 3.5,

**Set the Environment variables**

- set **python2** as the env variable for python2.7
- set **python** as evn variable for python3.5

**Install packages for python2:**
python2 -m pip install < package-name >

**Install packages for python3:**
python -m pip install < package-name >
or
pip install < package-name>

Answer (score -1):

Try `which pip`, choose your pip

then simply do `sudo /path_to_your_version_of_pip/pip install` your module